# Modernization of the JMS API in Java EE 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

A recent [Aquarium Blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_ee_7_devoxx_keynote) mentions a modernization of the JMS API to be included in Java EE 7. Are there any information resources on the Internet on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of [JSRs](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/all) (Look at [JSR 316](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316)).  When more details become available they will create a JSR for Java EE 7 and until then everything is speculation.

Reading the article you posted there is a telling quote:

> Of course, all it's still early days and a lot can change once the expert groups form and get to work.

Basically EE 7 is in the very early days and the standardization process hasn't even really started.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few words being said about this on Devoxx '10:

> JMS is an old specification, which
>   need to evelove for addressing new
>   communication layers:
>
> - resolving specification ambiguities
> - standardized vendor extension
> - integration with other specifications
> - integration with the web tier
> - (websocket, JSON, NIO2)

It's not much yet, hopefully more will be revealed soon. There was btw also a JMS BOF at Devoxx. Perhaps someone took notes of that?

Answer (score 2):

There is now [JSR 343: JavaTM Message Service 2.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=343):

> Changes that will be considered by the
>   Expert Group for inclusion in this new
>   revision include, but are not limited
>   to, the following:
>
> - Changes to improve ease of development
> - Clarification of the relationship between the JMS and other Java EE
>     specifications
> - Definition of a new mandatory API to allow any JMS provider to be
>     integrated with any Java EE
>     application server
> - Extensions to support Java EE 7
> - Other enhancements as requested by the community